# Twig extension: custom tag with un-rendered body

Tags: twig, twig-extension

Is it possible to create a custom tag with an un-rendered body? E.g.

```
{% mytag 'home' %}Welcome at {{ homepage }}{% endmytag %}
```

I would like to have the value of the `{{ homepage }}` variable in the new mytag function.

Comment: What do you mean with "un-rendered"? That there is no actual output in the template after running that node?

Comment: The variable {{ homepage }} is in the main rendered file not set, so the body of the tag is 'Welcome at ' and should be 'Welcome at {{ homepage }}'

Comment: So you want to output the text "Welcome at {{ homepage }}"? How about `{% verbatim %}Welcome at {{ homepage }}{% endverbatim %}` or `Welcome at {{ '{{' }} homepage {{ '}}' }}`?

Comment: You mean something like [this](https://twigfiddle.com/vzqxbo)?

Comment: verbatim is indeed a solution, but I prefer a situation without `verbatim`, is that possible? @DarkBee, I don't want te make use of the 'block' element.

Comment: How about `Welcome at {{ '{{ homepage }}' }}`?

Comment: There are a lot of variables in the body of the tag, so this is neither the best solution I think.

Comment: Okay, so why is `verbatim` not a good solution?

Answer (score 0):

Like the [Twig's documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#escaping) says, there are two standard ways (i.e. no need to create a Twig extension) to escape code, i.e. to prevent Twig from parsing `{{ variables }}` and `{% blocks %}`:

1. `{% verbatim %}Welcome at {{ homepage }}{% endverbatim %}`
2. `Welcome at {{ '{{ homepage }}' }}` or `Welcome at {{ '{{' }} homepage {{ '}}' }}`

If these options don't suit you, please be more specific about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: That is indeed correct, but the case is that it is a Twig Extension since I would like to have a custom tag. So, in that case, it could be more easy to skip the `verbatim` in the code.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to create a custom tag which behaves exactly like `verbatim`? In your question you have `{% mytag 'home' %}`, what's the purpose of `'home'`?

Comment: There are multiple params in the mytag, home is just an example

Comment: Now I'm confused because in your question you don't specify what the params are for. Please update your question with more details about what you are trying to do and why `verbatim` isn't a viable option in your case.